# I want to write to a Django model from a standalone python script that generates a CSV file but seem to be in the wrong environment

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I have a standalone python script that is run regularly, automatically, to generate a CSV file from external data.

I would like if this script could also update a corresponding model in a Django app running in a virtualenv.

I have added the following lines to the script

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from app.models import BER_assessors
```

The model is BER_assessors and is defined in the model.py file in the app directory at the root of the django application. The script is also at the root of the django application ( the one that contains the app/authentication/core/env/media etc. folders )

When I run my script I get the error message "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." The Django application itself runs fine.

I think there is a question of context or environment, i.e. I am not "in" the app and as such cannot write to the models etc.
How can I correct this ?

Best regards / Colm

Comment: you mean update the database?  why not create a migration? Then  run that migration with a subprocess.

Comment: If it is not supposed to be a migration and is a routine task consider writing a management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

The correct order for stand-alone scripts is:

```py
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'module.settings')
django.setup()

# other django related imports can now be done.
```

Comment: Thanks @Melvyn, this looks like the path. 

In the second line, if I am running the standalone script in the same core folder as settings.py can I just replace the 'module.settings' with just 'settings' ?

Comment: In theory yes. In practice this depends on the references in the settings file and PYTHONPATH. For example, your `ROOT_URLCONF` and `WSGI_APPLICATION` settings will most likely refer to `module.urls` and `module.wsgi:application` respectively. The path of least resistance is to run scripts from the directory where `manage.py` is located.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the answer above to work. It kept on telling me that other modules were not defined. So after digging, it turns out that I needed to activate the virtualenv to make all these modules available.

[This page](https://blog.aeguana.com/2015/07/31/stand-alone-django-script/) gave me the right direction and I ended up adding the following at the top of the file.

```
activate_this = '/full_path_to.../env/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read())
import sys
sys.path.append("/full_path_to.../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
django.setup()
```

No more error messages, the script is now working.

The script is in the root folder of the django installation, the settings.py file is in the core subfolder